# Django CMS - Unsafe attempt to load URL <URL> from frame with URL <URL>. Domains, protocols and ports must match

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-cms

I have all my django cms files on aws s3. I have problems with loading icons.svg from aws s3. I keep getting this message

*"Unsafe attempt to load URL  from frame with URL . Domains, protocols and ports must match."*

The rest of my files loads without any issue its just the icons.svg that does not load correctly. Im using Heroku, with the heroku domain.

Does anyone know how i solve this?

Comment: When you say "all my django cms files on aws s3" do you mean all your static files? You'll have to share some code for this. First off, settings, what is `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_STORAGE`. Also, how are you trying to load the file(s) which cause problems?

Comment: Are the icons in a different buket?